# summing value from fields (virtual fields)

Tags: mysql

i want to know if is possible to do something like this in mysql:

```
select 5 as a, 1 as b, a + b as c;
```

the problem is because i have this:

```
CONVERT( SUM(ifnull(commission,0.00)) ,DECIMAL(6,2)) as 'commission',
CONVERT( SUM(ifnull(income,0.00)) ,DECIMAL(6,2)) as 'income',
CONVERT( (SUM(ifnull(income,0.00)) - SUM(ifnull(commission,0.00))) ,DECIMAL(6,2)) as 'profit'
```

and of course the 3rd line would be more optimus if it dont have to SUM all the values again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do

```
select 5 as a, 1 as b, a + b as c;
```

but you can do

```
select a, b, a + b as c from (select 5 as a, 1 as b) as whatever;
```

(This is a nested query, which acts as a fake table when used from the outer query).

Applying thys to your case, we'd have:

```
select comission, income, income - comission from (
    select
        CONVERT( SUM(ifnull(commission,0.00)) ,DECIMAL(6,2)) as 'commission',
        CONVERT( SUM(ifnull(income,0.00)) ,DECIMAL(6,2)) as 'income'
    FROM ...
) as t
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If query has no GROUP BY clause you could use variables -

```
SELECT @a:=SUM(1), @b:=SUM(2), @c:=@a + @b FROM table
```

Also, subquery can be used here.

Comment: mmm im using group by =( but is very useful this information, thanks!

Comment: If query is simple, varaibles can be used, otherwise calculation can be unpredictable. So, subquery is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, b, a+b as c 
from ( 
   select 5 as a, 1 as b
) t
```